# gcsfuse won't write to folder

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I am trying to figure out why if I don't need to do this step

```
(Ubuntu before wily only) Add yourself to the fuse group, then log out and back in:

sudo usermod -a -G fuse $USER
exit
```

Then why can't I write to files; I keep getting the following error:

```
Using mount point: /mnt/c/Users/russe/Documents/gstorage
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running fusermount: exit status 1

stderr:
fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

I am using Ubuntu (on Windows App Store).

Even running:

```
sudo mount -t gcsfuse -o implicit_dirs,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000,key_file=/mnt/c/Users/russe/Documents/RadioMedia-ba86f56a2aa6.json radiomediapod
cast gstorage
```

had an error:

```
Calling gcsfuse with arguments: --uid 1000 --gid 1000 --key-file /mnt/c/Users/russe/Documents/RadioMedia-ba86f56a2aa6.json -o rw --implicit-dirs -o allow_other radiomediapodcast /mnt/c/Users/russe/Documents/gstorage
Using mount point: /mnt/c/Users/russe/Documents/gstorage
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: running fusermount: exit status 1

stderr:
fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first

running gcsfuse: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having might be because of two things:

-Permissions on the OS after mounting, to solve this mount your bucket with the following command:

`sudo mount -t gcsfuse -o implicit_dirs,allow_other,uid=1000,gid=1000,key_file=<KEY_FILE>.json <BUCKET> <PATH>`

-Permissions of your service account, to validate this you can go on the console to IAM & admin and verify that the service account being used has Storage Admin Role.

Comment: I used gcloud auth application-default login

Comment: the ubuntu computer you are using is it a VM in GCP or where is it?